# FileReader/BufferedReader gives me old values back

Tags: java, bufferedreader

a methode in my application writes something out in a file. After this I read the written and some other information in with the same application. This works good. But when my application adds some information to the file (outwriting works), and I try to read them in, I always get the old information, which I have read in before, while in the file the data has changed. The format in the file is correct and the information is there (I checked the file) and I'm using always the same methode for reading.
Here is my methode for reading in:

```
public int read(String path) {
    int ret = 0;
    String line = "";
    String[] data = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        line = br.readLine();
        int j = 0;
        while (line != null) {
            data = null;
            data = line.split(" ");
            //in the following line I always get an IndexOutOfBoundsError, after I got the old Information
    load.add(new Load(l[j].getNr(), l[j].getLength(), l[j].getWidth(), l[j].getHight(),
                    Integer.valueOf(data[4]), Integer.valueOf(data[5]), Integer.valueOf(data[6]),
                    Integer.valueOf(data[7]), l[j].getColor()));
            line = br.readLine();
            j++;
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " " + e.getClass());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Here is the methode for writing:

```
public void write() {
    try {
        File t = new File("data.3kp");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(t));
        for (int i = 0; i < load.size(); i++) {
            bw.write(load.get(i).getLength() + " " + load.get(i).getWidth() + " " + load.get(i).getHeight());
         bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error during writing to file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./3dbpp data.3kp 0 0 0 0");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me. I have no idea whats going wrong!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have copies of your file someplace around ?

Comment: No, the read-methode gets always the same path.

Comment: how are you determining you're getting the old information ? I mean what is that you expect it to change but doesn't ? the `load` variable ?

Comment: I'm checking, what the application has wrote in the file and I print out the variable "data" (the readed line). After I got printed out the last line from the old information, I get printed out the completly last line in the file (it jumps over the new information), but also only the half. So I get the IndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: hmm can you show us the format of the file ? anyway `data[4]`,`data[5]` are probably to blame for IndexOutOfBounds exception

Comment: This is the format of one line:
1 50 50 50 1 690 100 0

Comment: does every line have that format ?

Comment: side notes : 1-`data = null` inside loop isn't needed because you're assigning `line.split(" ")` to it right after -2- `fr` variable isn't really needed, `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));` is enough -3- `br.close()` will call `fr.close()`

Comment: Yes, every line has the same format

Comment: honestly I'm confused about what's happening :O, can you show us the method which writes to the file ?

Comment: @niceman I've added the write methode to my question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: "1 50 50 50 1 690 100 0" is 1 `load.get(i).getLength()`, first 50 `load.get(i).getWidth()`, second 50 `load.get(i).getHeight()` ?

Comment: in my opinion, the problem is with the program `3dbpp`(which you developed I guess), if you're verifying the file with that program, that program might be buggy and shows you that the file has things that don't exist(we can trust java's `BufferedReader` for sure :) )

Comment: I'm reading the output from 3dpp in, and this output is for sure correct. I have checked the outputfile many times (I thought also this can be the issue). I also don't think, that this is a bug of BufferedReader (that's impossible ;) ).

Answer (score 0):

You use static indexes to access values from a dynamically created array (`data[5]`, `data[6]`, etc.) as mentioned also in the comments. It is only a matter of time when such things cause you trouble. Either read it dynamically or ensure that you always have all the indexes available which you want to access, e.g.

```
data = line.split(" ");
Integer value1, value2, value3;
if (data.length > 4) {
    value1 = Integer.valueOf(data[4]);
}
// or if you know that all values you require are there as soon as length > 7 is reached:
if (data.length > 7) {
    value2 = Integer.valueOf(data[5]);
    value3 = Integer.valueOf(data[6]);
    value4 = Integer.valueOf(data[7]);
}
...
// and then use your values in the constructor of your Load-class:
load.add(new Load(l[j].getNr(), l[j].getLength(), l[j].getWidth(), l[j].getHight(),
                value1, value2,
                value3, value4, l[j].getColor()));
```

But as some information is missing from your question this was only a guess. Please copy the whole code or ensure that you have copied everything which is required to reproduce the problem.
How is `l` intialized? Or should it in fact be `data`?

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: Of course, you are right, but I cannot comment unless I have >= 50 reputation. As no one else asked what I was asking and as it seems to be required to get a useful answer, I posted it as an answer. I will adapt my answer if the question is adapted or delete it otherwise. At least on my own posts I can comment :-)

Comment: I see. In that case, if you edit your post a little bit, I can remove the minus score I gave to you. Without an edit my scoring is locked.